# Assuming different integration variable when squaring

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, stochastic-processes

I will start with an example. The guassian integral - to compute it, one can square it and change one integration variable:

$\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}} d x\right)^{2}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}} d x \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^{2}} d y=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)} d x d y=...=\pi$

Why is this change of integration variable allowed? By doing this, one calculates a double integral instead of a simple one. Obviously this means both variables were assumed to be independent from the start, but I do not understand why this assumption is valid.

And a followup question:
Let $X(t)$ be a stochastic process. Does the following hold

$<X^2>=<X(t) \cdot X(t)>=<X(t) \cdot X(t')>?$

Comment: The variable in an integral is a dummy variable – it has no relation to anything outside the integral. So the better question would be: Why should both variables be $x$ in the first place? In fact these two $x$'s have nothing to do with each other; they disappear outside the integral. It's like the index varaible in a sum: $\sum_{i=1}^3 a_i = \sum_{j=1}^3 a_j = a_1+a_2+a_3$.

Comment: Thinking in terms of a sum indeed helps, I should have thought about it more, I think my confusion in  the first example can be summarized as $(\sum_{i=1}^3 a_i)^2=\sum_{i=1}^3 a_i \cdot \sum_{i=1}^3 a_i =\sum_{i=1}^3 a_i \cdot \sum_{j=1}^3 a_j=a_1 a_1+a_1 a_2+..+a_3 a_3 \neq \sum_{i=1}^3 a_i^2 = a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2$. And the followup question probably relates more to $<\cdot^2>\neq<\cdot>^2$. Thanks